# Multiple languages in varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, multilingual, varchar, nvarchar

Can we store multilingual text in `varchar`? I used to believe that for these scenarios, we need to have a `nvarchar`, but when I tried the below code it worked fine.

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100)
SET @name='Hej mit navn er Vaibhav'
SELECT @name
```

**So should I take `varchar` or `nvarchar` to store multilingual text.**

Comment: `varchar` is fine as long as you don't need Unicode support - for languages like Hebrew, Arabic, Cyrillic, Chinese, Japanese, Korean etc. **Be aware:** `nvarchar` always uses 2 bytes for each character

Answer (score 3):

`nvarchar` stores [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters (which supports many more characters), `varchar` does not.  Since `'Hej mit navn er Vaibhav'` does not contain any Unicode characters, it works just fine.

> So should I take varchar or nvarchar to store multilingual text.

That depends on your situation. `nvarchar` takes twice as much space as `varchar` so if you have a large database and you will never need to store the extra character sets, `varchar` would make sense.  However space may not be an issue for you with a smaller database and you may prefer to use the extra space to allow for Unicode characters in the future.

Since specifically ask about *multilingual text*, I would say it is likely you would encounter characters that `varchar` cannot store.

Comment: Note that with Unicode compression in 2008 R2+ (Enterprise only unfortunately), nvarchar vs. varchar is largely moot unless you have a large number and wide variance of Unicode character sequences on any given page. Otherwise nvarchar compresses all non-Unicode characters as if they were varchar.

Answer (score 1):

Use Nvarchar datatype

```
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(100) 
SET @name=N'Hej mit navn er Vaibhav' 
SELECT @name
```

Comment: If you don't really need it, you're wasting 100% space - each `nvarchar` string always uses twice as much storage as a `varchar` string. Those extra bytes have to be stored, loaded from disk, passed over the network ......

Comment: @marc_s true unless using Unicode compression (see my other comment).

Comment: @AaronBertrand: ah - interesting! Thanks. Wasn't aware of the new feature in 2008 R2!